# Testing that all Intercepts of Different Regressions are Zero

Tags: hypothesis-testing, econometrics, f-test

I have individually regressed the excess returns of 10 US stocks on excess market returns.

Each have provided me with different $\alpha$'s.

I want to test whether these are all jointly equal to zero on STATA, or even Excel. Preferably STATA since I can not derive Newey-West estimators for standard errors on Excel.

Thank you.

Comment: You want to do a GRS test (finance term). Search for that.

Comment: @MatthewGunn. Phew, this is tedious but I'm making progress. Thanks, Matthew. I've been doing some reading and it seems this statistic assumes errors are normally distributed and homoskedastic. Is the GRS statistic the best we can do? 

Assuming I have used the GRS commands correctly in my statistical package, the output is:

**You are testing a single factor model with 1 factor MktRF and 10 portfolios. The GRS test statistic is:  .51615222 and the p-value is:  .87047155.** Thoughts?

Comment: I have no way of knowing whether you coded things properly, but it doesn't sound obviously implausible. To reject the CAPM (which appears to be what you are testing) you need portfolios of stocks that have statistically significantly different average returns and where the variation in average returns is not explained by variation in market beta. Go download the 25 Fama-French size, book to market portfolios and you will overwhelmingly reject the CAPM if you do your test on those.

Comment: This link from [John Cochrane may also be of interest.](https://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/john.cochrane/teaching/35150_advanced_investments/Cochrane_asset_pricing_CH12_229-250.pdf)